# Trigger numeric keyboard for input text all mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

Is there a way to trigger the numeric keyboard for a `<input type="text" />` field for all mobile devices?

I've tried both:

`<input type="text"  pattern="\d*" />`

`<input type="text"  pattern="[0-9]*" />`

But this only seems to trigger the numeric keyboard for iOS. Android still displays the default keypad.

---

Note: I'm trying to do a duration input, ie. HH:MM, so `<input type="number" />` is not a solution for this as I need a input field that will accept numbers and colons.

I also don't mind using javascript if that's the only solution.

Comment: i tried with <input type="tel" inputmode="numeric" pattern=" /*your pattern*/ "> and it worked for showing numeric keyboard on iOS

Answer (score -1):

I didn't try this but I did see some solutions in the past:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" inputmode="numeric">
```

Or:

```
<input type="number" pattern="[0-9]*" required>
```

I think type=tel is also supported but never tried it:

```
<input type="tel">
```

[Here](https://miketaylr.com/pres/html5/forms2.html) you have few examples.

Comment: This doesn't work on android devices.

Comment: @Ryan King Have you found solution? :)

Comment: Nope. Doesn't look like there is one right now...

Comment: this is not working

Comment: `inputmode="numeric"` appears to be the [standardized](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/interaction.html#input-modalities:-the-inputmode-attribute) approach - although [browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=input-inputmode) currently excludes Firefox and Safari, this is on track to become the standard, so they should eventually follow suit.